# Can I \include sub-documents that employ gregorio?

Tags: include, gregorio

I'd like to better manage a large latex document that incorporates many gregorio scores, by breaking it down into a main tex document and a number of sub-documents, incorporated into main with `\include`.  Each of the sub-documents has text and one or more invocations of `\gregorioscore`.

`\include` requires me to strip all preamble from the included document, i.e. everything up to and including `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

When I do this and compile the main document, a pdf is generated which includes the material from main and text from the included documents, but not the included documents' gregorio scores.  Compilation gives underfill and overfill errors that I didn't get when I compiled the sub-documents separately (with their preamble added).  My question is: can I `\include` sub-documents that employ gregorio, or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question, as I worked out what the problem was.

My included sub-document gave a path to the gregorio score (gabc file) relative to the sub-document's location.  When I changed the path to give it from the master document's location the compilation succeeded, and a pdf was output which included the gregorio score.